# VPN between a Server, a Raspberry Pi and a Smartphone

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

here's the problem I'm facing. I want to connect with a client (eg. smartphone via mobile network) to my server (which is connected via vpn to my rapsberry at home) so that I can access my home network securely from everywhere and also browse via my home internet connection through the web.

Is that somehow possible to achieve with my devices and openvpn and what I have to do? I'm really stuck at this... :/

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but this site is not here for providing complete solutions, but to help with something.... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Basically you need to make raspberry openvpn server, make your "server" connect to it, install openvpn server also there and then install openvpn client on your smartphone. Then your server will route it. But it is also possible to do without that intermediate server - from your phone directly to raspberry at home.

Comment: The problem is that my provider only offers a DSLite Tunnel, so I have problems to connect from the internet to my home network. My I idea is now to connect from my raspberry to my server which is accessible from the internet so that I can connect through this server to my home network. The VPN in the raspberry already fully configured, but I not really know how to connect from my raspberry to my server